# Create custom macro similar to __COUNTER__ in GCC plugin

Tags: c, gcc, plugins, macros, preprocessor

I am refactoring a program which requires types to have a global unique number which increases by one for every object (ie. the max unique number should be the the amount of types declared with this ID) in the entire project (`__COUNTER__` only works for the current file).

This currently looks like

```cpp
struct foo {
    static const int index = __GLOBAL_COUNTER__(TYPES, _3862e1e60a2749c2bfd2add9f3ddbb25);
};
```

A python script is run on this which runs the normal C++ processor then uses regex to find uses of `__GLOBAL_COUNTER__` and replaces them with a number. The macro argument number is the name of the counter to use and the second is a UUID (so that that the value is constant between includes).

Issues with approach is that the use of the macro doesn't work properly when mixed with other macros and the python script and regex can replace things I don't intend (eg. in strings). Also having to manually generate a UUID for each type is cumbersome.

So my question is whether it is possible to write a macro as a GCC plugin to provide this functionality and where I should start. I have searched the documentation and read some of the GCC source code, but I haven't found anything.

NOTE: this is generally merged into another macro to save a bit of typing

```cpp
#define TYPE_INDEX(x) static const int index = __GLOBAL_COUNTER__(TYPES, x);
```

So if there are other approaches for example changing the syntax so something like this if it is easier would also work, but I am not sure how I would go about it.

```cpp
indexed_struct foo {
};
```

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but I think if you define unique indexes for all of the files and if you OR that index and __GLOBAL__ value just after shifting the file index to the leftmost, you can generate project-wide unique integer values. Also you can create a library function to not to rewrite shifting and ORing stuff. --> generate_unique_number(file_index, __GLOBAL__)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have the constraint of requiring not only unique, but sequential indices at compile time. I think I use a similar approach when that constraint is not required (implementing a crude hashing function on `__FILE__` to create the file id).

Comment: You have to create a UUID for each type, that means you know all types beforehand. Why don't you create an enum with all these types?